# Woocommerce WP - Get _sku value from post_type = shop_order | SQL QUERY

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

**Woocommerce** has in **wp_posts** , two types of post_type, '***product***' & '***shop_order***'.

From the ***shop_order ID***, where can i get the ***_sku*** ? The ***wp_postmeta*** has the ***_sku*** and it connects directly to `post_type = 'product'` and not to the `post_type = 'shop_order'`. So far a have this :

```
SELECT 
    oi.order_item_id,
    oi.order_item_name,
    oi.order_item_type,
    oi.order_id,
    max( CASE WHEN oim.meta_key = '_line_subtotal' and oim.order_item_id = oi.order_item_id THEN oim.meta_value END ) as _line_subtotal,
    max( CASE WHEN oim.meta_key = '_line_total' and oim.order_item_id = oi.order_item_id THEN oim.meta_value END ) as _line_total,
    max( CASE WHEN oim.meta_key = '_product_id' and oim.order_item_id = oi.order_item_id THEN oim.meta_value END ) as _product_id,
    max( CASE WHEN oim.meta_key = '_variation_id' and oim.order_item_id = oi.order_item_id THEN oim.meta_value END ) as _variation_id,
    max( CASE WHEN oim.meta_key = '_qty' and oim.order_item_id = oi.order_item_id THEN oim.meta_value END ) as _quantaty
FROM
    wp_woocommerce_order_items oi INNER JOIN
    wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta oim on oi.order_item_id = oim.order_item_id
where oi.order_id=:order_item
    group by oi.order_item_id
    ");
$sth2->bindParam(':order_item', $_GET["order"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$sth2->execute();
```

How can i print in this SQL query the **_sku value** ? 
Where is the connection from the ***shop_order*** to the original page ID of the ***product*** `post_type = 'product'`

The _sku value is in wp_postmeta with:

```
post_id = where wp_post.ID (which is the ID of the product, not the shop_order)
meta_key = _sku
meta_value = my_sku_value_here
```

Comment: In other words where can i find the relationship between post_type = 'product' and post_type = 'shop_order' items.

Comment: An order has order items. Some order items are for products and have a product id. You will need to do a join on the tables wp_posts, wp_woocommerce_order_items, wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta, wp_posts and wp_postmeta.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the query to find woocommerce orders for a specific product :

```
select ord.ID
from wp_posts prd
join wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta om on om.meta_key = '_product_id' and om.meta_value = prd.ID
join wp_woocommerce_order_items o on o.order_item_id = om.order_item_id
join wp_posts ord on ord.ID = o.order_id
where prd.ID = [Specific product ID]
```